# SQL search in two columns with one combined value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I will try to demonstrate what I am trying to achieve. This is an oversimplified example for my case.

Suppose I have a table contains two columns

```
ID        YEAR
---       ----
1         2017
2         2018
```

and I have a search term  `2017 / 1`

What I want to do is something like this

```
select * from table where 'YEAR / ID' LIKE '%searchterm%'
```

Is this possible ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Below query, I have considered your search text format as `2017 / 1`.

```
DECLARE @tblTest AS Table
(
    Id INT,
    YearNo INT
)

INSERT INTO @tblTest values (1,2017)
INSERT INTO @tblTest values (2,2018)
INSERT INTO @tblTest values (3,2017)
INSERT INTO @tblTest values (4,2018)

DECLARE @searchterm VARCHAR(50)='2017 / 1'
```

**[LEFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql)** will give you string starting from left position to applied length.

**[RIGHT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/right-transact-sql)** will give you string starting from right position to applied length

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM @tblTest 
WHERE YearNo=LEFT(@searchterm,4)
AND Id = REPLACE(RIGHT(@searchterm,LEN(@searchterm)-(CHARINDEX('/',(REPLACE(@searchterm, ' ', ''))))),'/','')
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the most effective way is:

1. Firstly divide String x = "2017 / 1" to two int values int year = 2017, int id = 1. I don't know what kind of programing language you are using but all of programing languages have special functions to make it easily (between all values you have '/').
2. Then use this query:

   ```
   Select * 
   from table 
   where year = 2017 
     and id = 1
   ```

Comment: TSQL `SUBSTRING` could be used.

Comment: give solution in query instead

Answer (score 1):

**If your database compatibility could be 130** then You can Try `String_Split` ref https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql
Sql most long awaited function (as msdn says)

```
Declare @tbl table (id int Identity(1,1), value nvarchar(5))

Insert into @tbl ([value]) SELECT value from STRING_SPLIT(@searchstring,'/')   

Declare @id int
Select @id = cast(value as int) from @tbl where id=2 --will give 1

Declare @value int
Select @id = cast(value as int) from @tbl where id=1 --ill give 2017

--   —now use them in sql

select * from table where YEAR=@value and ID = @id
```

Answer (score 1):

You are going to screw up the performance if you do anything like below

> select * from table where 'YEAR / ID' LIKE '%searchterm%'

Best way is you can split your search and supply to respective col

```
  Declare @Search varchar(15)='2017/1'
        Declare @Year int = (select LEFT(@Search,CHARINDEX('/',@search)-1))
        Declare @month int = (select Right(@Search,(len(@search) -CHARINDEX('/',@search))))
        select * from #temp where id=@month and year=@Year
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
select * from table where YEAR + ' / ' + ID LIKE '%searchterm%'
```

this query will run, but it will perform very poor.

Comment: You're probably going to need some casts in there, since `ID` and `YEAR` appear to be numeric columns.