# SQL search columns separately with one combined keyword

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm building a search form to search first and last names in a table:

Table structure:

```
Column 1 - First Name
Column 2 - Last Name
```

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM customers 
WHERE first_name LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%'" . " OR 
    last_name LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%'"
```

This works fine if I search a first name separately or a last name separately.

How can I modify the query to search both a first name and last name together as one keyword and also still be able to search a first and last name separately?

Example: "Joe Shmoe"

With the above query, if I search "Joe Shmoe" it does not return any results.

I tried [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48436632/sql-search-in-two-columns-with-one-combined-value) but can't get it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT c.*
FROM customers c
WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name) LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%'" . "
```

Comment: Shouldn't the WHERE be ```CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, ' ',last_name)```? Maybe OR'ed with what you have,

Comment: @SloanThrasher The first param passed to `CONCAT_WS` is the separator. So, there's no need to pass another extra space. You'd need the extra space if you'd used `CONCAT` instead.